# Sort products alphabeticaly if prices are equal

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, filtering

For some reason when Woocommerce sorts by price, in case of equal price it resorts to sorting by product ID instead of alphabeticaly. It is really not intuitive for customers (who cares when was a product created? that should only apply to sorting by "new"). I want to change default sorting by price to resort to sorting alphabeticaly if prices are equal. Unfortunately my code doesn't achieve that. Does anyone happen to have a suggestion? Thank you.

```
    function replace_default_sorting_option($options) {
        $options['custom_sort'] = 'Custom Sort'; // Replace 'custom_sort' with your key and 'Custom Sort' with your label
        unset($options['price-desc']); // Remove the default price descending option
        return $options;
    }
    add_filter('woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'replace_default_sorting_option');
    
    function custom_product_sort($query) {
        if (is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query())
            return;
    
        if (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product()) {
            $orderby = $query->get('orderby');
    
            if ($orderby === 'custom_sort') {
                $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num title'); // Sort by price and title
                $query->set('order', 'DESC ASC'); // Price in descending order, title in ascending order
            }
        }
    }
    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_product_sort');
```

Failed attempt 2 (only sorts by title):

```
function replace_default_sorting_option($options) {
    $options['custom_sort'] = 'Custom Sort'; // Replace 'custom_sort' with your key and 'Custom Sort' with your label
    unset($options['price-desc']); // Remove the default price descending option
    return $options;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'replace_default_sorting_option');

function custom_product_sort($query) {
    if (is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query())
        return;

    if (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product()) {
        $orderby = $query->get('orderby');

        if ($orderby === 'custom_sort') {
            $query->set('orderby', array('meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'title' => 'ASC')); // Sort by price (numeric) and then by title
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_product_sort');
```

Failed attempt 3 (random? order):

```
function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby($orderby) {
    // Add your custom sorting option
    $orderby['custom_sort'] = 'Custom Sorting';
    return $orderby;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');
add_filter('woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');

function custom_product_sorting($query) {
    if (is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query())
        return;

    if (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product()) {
        $orderby = $query->get('orderby');

        if ($orderby === 'custom_sort') {
            $query->set('meta_query', array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                'price_clause' => array(
                    'key' => '_price',
                    'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                ),
                'title_clause' => array(
                    'key' => 'post_title',
                    'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                ),
            ));
            $query->set('orderby', array(
                'price_clause' => 'DESC',
                'title_clause' => 'ASC',
            ));
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_product_sorting');
```

Failed attempt 4 (sorts only by post title)?

```
function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby($orderby) {
    // Add your custom sorting option
    $orderby['custom_sort'] = 'Custom Sorting';
    return $orderby;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');
add_filter('woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');

function custom_product_sorting($query) {
    if (is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query())
        return;

    if (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product()) {
        $orderby = $query->get('orderby');

        if ($orderby === 'custom_sort') {
            $query->set('orderby', array(
                'price' => 'DESC', // Sort by price in descending order
                'title' => 'ASC',  // Then sort by title in ascending order
            ));
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_product_sorting');
```

Comment: Try with passing arrays instead: `$query->set('orderby', ['meta_value_num', 'title']);` and `$query->set('order', ['DESC', 'ASC']);`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but no luck, that doesn't sort neither by price nor by title, order seems random (well, I can't find any logic to it).

Comment: Ah, you have to omit the order and just use orderby like `$query->set('orderby' => ['meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'title' => 'ASC']);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query and Orderby multiple ACF Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43768562/query-and-orderby-multiple-acf-fields)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions Markus but unfortunately the first only sorts by title and the latter is back to random (?) order. Please see the code I pasted in post update. thank you

Comment: The orderby sorts table columns. As these are none, I suppose it can not be sorted. I do not use Wordpress, but at mySQL level you would use the `as` keyword. Have look here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30241/wp-query-order-results-by-meta-value. Finally, I would say, change the keys to just "price" and "title" without the "_clause" suffix and it should work.

Comment: I think `woocommerce_catalog_orderby` might be the wrong hook to begin with, I think that adds _new_ sort options? The `woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args` part from https://stackoverflow.com/a/53589762/1427878 is what you'd need here, I think. When the `orderby` value is `price`, then you want to return a modified array that includes your second sort criterion.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I fixed the suffixes but that still only sorts by price. What do you mean reegarding the orderby?

Comment: @CBroe I know that but for debugging purposes I want to have the sorting option separate until the logic works

Comment: I mean you should use `$query->set('orderby', ['price' => 'DESC', 'title' => 'ASC']);`,

Comment: Hmm like the attempt #4 (edited into main post)? Still only sorts by title.